# How to compare scores with different possible point totals

Tags: statistics

Is there way to fairly compare multiple scores with varying possible point totals such as 26/90, 54/70,67/80, etc...? This is based on the same test but not all questions apply to everyone taking it, so people don't lose or gain points if they are not able to answer. We also can not only compare questions relating to all participants. 90 is the maximum amount possible to score if all questions answered.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but which way is "fair" is in the eye of the beholder. You have to decide, for instance, what score out of 100 is as good as 10 out of 10. Once you have made a large number of decisions like that, then you can ask for formulas that accord with your decisions, not before.